# How to represent 3d vector as an array and individual components in C?

Tags: c

Sometimes it is simpler to view a 3d vector as an array of 3 values. But it makes the code cleaner when you are able to write `vec.y` to access individual components. How can I code my vector struct to allow both representations?

**Desired outcome: being able to code like this**

```
y_component = 3.0 * myvec.y

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%f", myvec.v[i])
}
```

**Currently I have this**

```
struct vector3 {
    double v[3];
    double *x, *y, *z;
};

// then inside an init function it already gets a little bit strange
myvec.v = (double [3]) {1.0, 3.0, -5.0};
myvec.x = &vector3.v[0];
myvec.y = &vector3.v[1];

// And accessing individual component can be confusing 
y_component = 3.0 * (*myvec.y);

// Its also strange when given a pointer to a vector3
y_component = 3.0 * (*ptr_myvec->y);
```

Unfortunately that is the best I could come up with, after looking at various implementations. But maybe some one has a way?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you using pointers, especially since in the desired outcome you don't dereference?

Comment: Did you try using a union?

Comment: I think this kind of cleverness will just confuse the maintainer of the program. I would simply go with `struct vector3 { double x, y, z; };`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Perhaps in this case, but there are other cases where the cleverness is useful. Suppose each struct contains 100 doubles with various meaningful names, but you are reading them from a file one by one. The code reading that file will be a mess  without using array notation.

Comment: @Lundin It will be more code but it will not be "a mess". It will be explicit and easy to understand. The "union" solution is not type safe and can easily break if changes are made that don't take C's padding rules into consideration.

Comment: @Lundin The alternative would be to use an array and define the "meaningful names" as an index enumeration.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Whenever you use structs/unions you must take padding in consideration. This case is no exception. Simply add a static assert and/or a `#pragma pack`, it is standard procedure when using structs "mapped" to represent a given memory area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a union. It gives you the ability to access the same memory cells by using different nomenclature:

```
typedef union {
  double v[3];

  struct
  {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
  };
} vector3;

vector3 vec;
static_assert(sizeof(vec) == sizeof(vec.v), "Err: padding detected!");

vec.v[0] = 1.0;
printf("%f", vec.x); // prints 1.0
```

---

Note: if you are using an older compiler, you have to do this this:

```
typedef union {
  double v[3];

  struct
  {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
  } s;
} vector3;

vector3 vec;

vec.v[0] = 1.0;
printf("%f", vec.s.x); // prints 1.0
```

Comment: @SzG This is standard C. If your C compiler is older than 3 years and only supports C99, then indeed name the struct.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I had to use a union, but could not figure out how. :)

Comment: One more question actually, since padding is allowed between members of a structure, does that mean that the struct could take more space than the union and that they would not align correctly? (although in practise they do align 99% of the time)

Comment: @user10607 Structs and unions follow the same padding rules. So if there is padding in a struct, there will be the very same padding in the corresponding union.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I meant if there is padding in a struct, but no padding in the *array*, then is it possible that `.y` of the struct aligns with (for example) the third element of the array. (The union would then of course be the size of the struct since struct is the larger element because of its padding).

Comment: @user10607 That is a concern. Padding in the inner struct is possible but unlikely. Use a static_assert to check for that.

Comment: Indeed. I've updated the code with an example of how to ensure there are no padding problems.

Comment: @2501 from what I see `static_assert` is a compile time thing. So that means I only have to perform this check once on program startup? (or do I have to do this for every instance?)

Comment: @user10607 Just once, somewhere in the code. See the example above.